# Oracle SQL: Why does last_day(SYSDATE) need to_date()?

Tags: sql, oracle

Yesterday, I changed one of our queries to pivot on sysdate.

In my where's and joins I used `last_day(SYSDATE)`  at first; however, this returned no data (This was filtering on a time_key column with date values).

When I changed the query to `to_date(last_day(SYSDATE))` the query returned data as it should.

I have heard that SYSDATE contains time as well as a date (Although, I don't see this in 
a `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;`).

Can anyone elaborate on why I need to call `to_date()` on my `last_day(SYSDATE)`? Shouldn't I have already had a date value?

Comment: Can you share the full query please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a big long for a comment.

The expression `last_day(sysdate)` works fine.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8) is a SQL Fiddle.

My guess is that the problem you are experiencing is that the time component is passed through, and you don't want the time.  In that case, just use `trunc()`.  The following are equivalent:

```
trunc(last_day(sysdate))
last_day(trunc(sysdate))
```